# adsense management api give diffrent results than website

Tags: adsense-api

adsense management api give me different results than the website interface.

the simplest example:
run the report here:
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/reports/generate

I want to see the rpm by countries for given AD_UNIT_NAME for some date

this the request:(xxxx is censored
https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.4/accounts/pub-xxxx/reports?startDate=2014-05-01&endDate=2014-05-01&dimension=COUNTRY_CODE&filter=AD_UNIT_NAME%3D%3D160%2F600+-+xxxx&metric=AD_REQUESTS_RPM&key=xxxx

I get the results as excepted  the problem is when i go the adsense website and click on the same ad unit name, and add country dimension I see different results.. i checked it a lot of times with all kind of differents request(for example clicks instead of rpm or different ad unit or without country dimensions and so on).

the api always give different results than adsense interface why is that?

api results example:
[
   "BR",
   "5.10"
  ]

adsense website results for same ad:
brazil: 7.64

what i tried:

make sure same currency.
make sure same dates.
check different dates.
check its the same ad.
check different ads.
etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so after long time I found the answer:
different time zone...
all was needed was to set useTimezoneReporting to true.

I think it should be the default value..

Comment: The default setting is false due to legacy reasons, as timezone reporting wasn't available when the API was first developed.